# How can I run fast my project?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Here is my database.properties file which use for store database
    information

```
 ################### JDBC Configuration ##########################
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eduman_em?
verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false&requireSSL=false
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=1234

 ########## Hibernate Configuration #########
  hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
  #### hibernate.show_sql=true
  #### hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
  #### hibernate.generate_statistics=true
  hibernate.connection.charSet=UTF-8
  hibernate.ejb.naming_
  strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
  hibernate.cache.provider_class=
  org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider
  ################## For List insertion Hiber Config    
  ###hibernate.order_inserts=true###
  ####hibernate.order_updates=true####

This is my **applicationContext-db.xml**



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd">


<!-- Scan for property files -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:META-INF/spring/*.properties"/>

    <!-- Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
    <!-- Detect @Transactional -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


    <!-- Entity Manager Factory -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <!-- Define Hibernate JPA Vendor Adapter -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
           <!-- <property name="generateDdl" value="true" /> -->
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
        </bean>
        </property>
        <!-- Persistence Unit -->
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
    </bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" p:url="${jdbc.url}"
        p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
        <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

I use mysql database. my database size 552 MB. when I run my project it takes more then 5 min.If I use 100 MB below/small database then it run fast. How can I run first my project.
Thanks.

Comment: Is this seriously your question? You provide your database config, state its size and complain about the 'project' being slow and al you tag this question with is PrimeFaces? And your title 'just' states 'spring hibernate jpa' of which only 'hibernate' seems directly related. Since you already have 19 reputation points I'm 100% sure you can do better and I am retagging your question

Comment: Sir, I added database config file and database size

Answer (score 0):

@ Nasir

You can go for Hikari Connection Pool.Return Hikari DataSource object.Sample code as below :

```
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;


@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    // In classpath from spring-boot-starter-web
    final Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("driverClassName", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    props.put("jdbcUrl", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/master?createDatabaseIfNotExist=false");
    props.put("username", "root");
    props.put("password", "mysql");
    HikariConfig hc = new HikariConfig(props);
    HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(hc);
    return ds;
}
```

Comment: Sir, I can't use this class because when I export war file then I can't change database url,username and password. I need to change database url,username and password after export war file.

Comment: I am not saying to change your database details....what i meant to say is use Hikari Connection Pooling on top of ur Datasource...    
HikariConfig hc = new HikariConfig(props);
HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(hc);

Comment: Sir I can also use  HikariDataSource but problem not solve.